# select last 5 sale by customer?

Tags: sql

I have a simple table called `sales` with columns

```
createdon, saleid, customerid
```

other table I have `customer` table with columns

```
customerid, name, etc..
```

now I need last 5 sales by client,

in other table called `scanned` I have

```
scannedid,saleid,customerid
```

I believe I need to have the last 5 salesid by client for I get what clients
were scanned in their last 5 sales ( sales are not same days for example a customer is visited monday a saturday, but other is visited tuesday and thursday but this information is not important for this example)

My real question is

**How to get the customersid which were scanned in their last 5 sales?**

For that I believe I do need the query for get last 5 salesid by client
for example.i have 3 customers, then i'll need the last 5 sales, of customer1, customer2, and customer3, then i'll have 15 saleid returned

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you want exactly. Can you perhaps give us a small set of sample data, and a sample of the output you want from that data?

Comment: select last 5 salesid by customerid not using a loop @Blorgbeard

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By client, I assume you mean customerid.  I think you want the first five records from sales, based on the createdon date in descending order.  The exact syntax depends on the database.  Here is one way:

```
select top 5 customerid
from sales s
order by createdon desc
```

And another way:

```
select customerid
from sales s
order by createdon desc
limit 5
```

And another way:

```
select *
from (select customerid, rownum as seqnum
      from sales
      order by createdon
     ) s
where seqnum <= 5
```

Now that you've clarified what you want, it is easy:

```
select *
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by created on desc) as seqnum
      from sales s
     ) s
where seqnum <= 5
```

Comment: that is not i need, i need for every customer, his last 5 sales

Comment: @angel . . . That greatly clarifies what you need.  See the last part of the revised answer.

Comment: that last part return that i wanted!